# Calling a native FORTRAN function from C# corrupts the sent matrix

Tags: c#, fortran, dllexport

I'm testing calling FORTRAN functions from a DLL,
here's the code

**The function in FORTRAN**

```
! This subroutine is for multiplying two matrices
! A(m,n) * B(n,k) = C(m,k)
subroutine MatrixMultiplication(m, n, k, A, B, C)
    !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: MatrixMultiplication
    !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'MatrixMultiplication' :: MatrixMultiplication

!---------------------------------------------------
    implicit none
!---------------------------------------------------    
    integer, intent(in)  :: m,n,k
    real*8,  intent(in)  :: A(m,n), B(n,k)
    real*8,  intent(out) :: C(m,k)
    integer              :: i, j
!---------------------------------------------------

    ! Print matrix A and B to check if they are passed correctly

    open(unit=1, file="A.txt", status="replace")
    open(unit=2, file="B.txt", status="replace")
    open(unit=3, file="C.txt", status="replace")
    open(unit=4, file="variables.txt", status="replace")

    write(4,*) m,n,k

    do i=1,m
        write(1,100) ( A(i,j), j=1,n )
    end do

    do i=1,n
          write(2,100) ( B(i,j), j=1,k )
    end do

    C = matmul(A,B)

    ! write C to a text file
    do i=1,m
          write(3,100) ( C(i,j), j=1,k )
    end do

100 format(10f10.5)      
    return
end subroutine
```

**Implementation in C#**

```
    [DllImport(DLLname, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void MatrixMultiplication(ref int m, ref int n,ref int k, 
                    [In] double[,] A, [In] double[,] B, [Out] double[,] C);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[,] A = new double[,]
        {
            { 1,2,3,4,5,6 },
            { 1,2,3,4,5,6 },
            { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }
        };

        double[,] B = new double[,]
        {
            { 1,2,3 },
            { 1,2,3 },
            { 1,2,3 },
            { 1,2,3 },
            { 1,2,3 },
            { 1,2,3 }
        };

        int m = A.GetLength(0);
        int n = A.GetLength(1);
        int k = B.GetLength(1);
        double[,] C = new double[m, k];

        MatrixMultiplication(ref m, ref n, ref k, A, B, C);

    }
```

**A.txt**

```
1.00000        4.00000        1.00000        4.00000        1.00000        4.00000
2.00000        5.00000        2.00000        5.00000        2.00000        5.00000
3.00000        6.00000        3.00000        6.00000        3.00000        6.00000
```

**B.txt**

```
1.00000        1.00000        1.00000
2.00000        2.00000        2.00000
3.00000        3.00000        3.00000
1.00000        1.00000        1.00000
2.00000        2.00000        2.00000
3.00000        3.00000        3.00000
```

It seems the passed matrix in fortran is filled by columns instead of rows!!
Any solution?

Comment: It is a feature, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: Any solution? Fill the array transposed or transpose it afterwards. Or change the order of indexes when working with it.